# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

-- This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
Payment_id BIGINT NOT NULL primary key,
Ord_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Ord_id)
    REFERENCES Ord(Ord_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
Bank_id int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (Bank_id)
    REFERENCES Bank(Bank_id),
card_id varchar(16),
 cvv varchar(3),
expired_date date not null,                         
total_price decimal(11,2),
payment_date datetime

)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and this is some datas

```
INSERT INTO Payment (Payment_id,
Ord_id ,
Bank_id ,
card_id ,
 cvv ,
expired_date,                       
total_price ,
payment_date)
VALUES
(1,1,1,'3998181978445452','854','2023-10-16','350000','2019-10-16 16-45-10'),
(2,2,2,'3994191845663215','125','2022-10-16','840000','2019-10-16 17-45-10'),
(3,3,3,'3998181978446666','814','2021-10-16','1260000','2019-10-16 18-30-10'),
(4,4,1,'3998181978446666','814','2024-10-17','600000','2019-10-17 11-25-10'),
(5,5,2,'3998181978446666','814','2023-10-17','200000','2019-10-17 12-24-14'),
(6,6,3,'3998181978446666','814','2020-10-17','200000''2019-10-17 15-12-17'),
(7,7,1,'3998181978446666','814','2021-10-17','280000','2019-10-17 15-41-12');
```

but its not working and the error message is "1136"

Comment: You are missing a comma on this line (6,6,3,'3998181978446666','814','2020-10-17','200000'**'2019-10-17 15-12-17'), - highlighted with **

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma at line 6;

```
 (6,6,3,'3998181978446666','814','2020-10-17','200000' #HERE#  '2019-10-17 15-12-17')
```